# Using Gridgain visor gui with Ignite cluster

Tags: gridgain, ignite

I have a cluster with Apache Ignite nodes, is it possible somehow to use  visor GUI version with it? when I run Gridgain Gui version I get an exception of using Gridgain node with ignite node.
I understand that it is an enterprise version and it is a paid version, but I want to know posibility in trial period. have I reconstruct my system with gridgain instead of ignite or is there any adapters or somthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the GridGain edition, not the Apache Ignite edition, to work with Visor GUI. Please download the evaluation copy from the website which should be good for 30 days: http://www.gridgain.com/download/editions/#enterprise-edition

Someone will get in touch with you to provide an extended evaluation license if needed.

Comment: Does this means, when ignite is started, I cant discover it with Visor GUI?

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the Visor GUI and Web Console developers.

You may use trial Visor GUI with Ignite grid if Ignite grid deployed only on ONE host. And you should use only external connect, because in internal connect mode Visor will start GG demon node and it will not connect to Ignite cluster.

As Dmitriy already suggested you may download 30 day trial GridGain distributive and run GG cluster instead of Ignite cluster. GG cluster is just a plugin for Ignite cluster and if you do not configure ENT features it will be the same as Ignite. But you cannot mix GG and Ignite nodes one cluster.

Also you can try visor command line, it is a part of Ignite distribution.
See: [Visor command Line](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/command-line-interface).

And about Web Console, monitoring will work only with cluster started from latest [nightly build](https://ignite.apache.org/community/contribute.html#nightly-builds) . Because we implemented monitoring support after ignite-1.6 was released. Or you may wait for ignite-1.7.

Answer (score -1):

How about using the GridGain/Ignite web-console? Here is the link: https://console.gridgain.com/

Comment: it fails to get connected to the existing cache of Ignite... !

Comment: What Ignite version?